# Flag and downvote without delay

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, spam, time-limit

I post a question today in **server fault** and I get two **spam answers**.

So, I try down vote this 2 answers and then flag it, but SO It's not allowed that:

[image: flag a answer not allowed]

**Link to my question:** https://serverfault.com/questions/704052/correctly-way-to-store-images-in-server

I know if SO enable to flag and down vote without delay maybe this cause a server overheating but, the possible solution for that is put some validation, like a reCAPTCHA when the user try to do the same action more then 1 time.

For me, this is really useful because I'm not remember every time what question has the spam or some bad answers. So, when I open the question, in a normal day I want to do what I need to do: answer, upvote, downvote, flag, delete, edit - every action in the same moment.

Anyway, thanks.

Remember: this is just a suggestion, I do not want to fight here.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to downvote if you flag as spam. With a spam flag comes a free downvote.

Comment: Are you really saying you can't wait 5 seconds?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I would not have created this question. I know they are only 5 seconds to you, but most of the time I get on stackoverflow I'm at work, so for me at least is a little odd look at the screen and count, 1 .. 2 .. 3 .. 4 .. 5 .. to do this for one or more answers / questions. Sometimes I just want to do what I have to do here, close the browser tab and continue working, and in most cases I do not know when I'll come back on this question, then what I should have done, I ended up not doing it for "only 5 seconds".

Comment: @rene about downvote and flag, thanks. I don't know that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems a throttling thing in place to prevent massive flagging through scripts or a user error.

I had the error message too, and it was the first time in about 2000 flags I have seen it. Not a real issue. I think the throttling is more important than a once-in-a-while error.

See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/245360) where it states this behavior.

Comment: Yes, I agreed with you. It's not a common case, but happens some times. Anyway, thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @rene yeah, you right.